# Open a specific fragment of activity A from activity B

Tags: java, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

Here again!

The situation is this, I have:

Activity A that implements a viewPager and visualizes 3 possible fragments. To access to each fragment I use this code:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int page) {
        switch (page) {
            case 0: return new MyFirstFragment();
            case 1: return new MySecondFragment();
            case 2: return new MyThirdFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return [the count of total fragments];
    }
```

Fragment 3 contains a list of users. When I click on a user Activity B is started. Using intent:

```
// Create new Intent Object, and specify class
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(Fragment3.this, ActivityB.class);
//Use startActivity to start Activity B
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity B there is button that redirects me to Fragment 2. So the question is: how can I return see Fragment number 2? I was thinking to start again the activity A and using putExtra to specify which fragment should be visualized.

For example I would pass a number, 2 in this case, and would like to call the function Fragment getItem(2) to visualize the fragment. However, Fragment getItem is contained in the pageadapter class, so I am unclear about how to proceed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution by my own :)

I used intent.putExtra() to pass the position of the fragment which I wanted to display, then in the called activity I used the method setCurrentItem(position) of ViewPager and the wanted fragment is displayed.

Hope this can help someone else who will have my same problem!

Comment: Thanks for this quick hack!